# django is serving static css files, yet somehow js files show a 404

Tags: django, django-templates

when i try to include js files in my template, as opposed to css files - django can't point the browser to the static folder... 
this is the relevant part in my settings.py -

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

from within my template, when i'm calling css files as in the following example -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}" />
```

they get loaded just fine -

```
 "GET /static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 127343
```

yet, when i try to load js files like so -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/bootstrap/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
```

the request gets broken, and in the runserver terminal window i get errors like -

```
"GET /bootstrap/js/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2848
```

showing that the 'static' part of the url gets dropped out... 
anyone has an idea as for why this is happening? thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I usually use:

```
<a href="{{ STATIC_URL }}path/to/file">
```

So:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}bootstrap/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and this works for js files fine.  So maybe try this as opposed to the `{% static %}` tag to see if it works.

Comment: thanks, but i figured out it was another thing... both {{ STATIC_URL }} and {% static %} works...
the problem was i had to remove the leading slashes before the file's location... for some reason, it broke django's url construction... note than in my original message the css file didn't had any prefix slash while the js file did...

and again - thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  When using Django URLs they don't need a leading slash because Django takes care of that part automatically.  Cool, glad it worked.  Enjoy your Django journey.  It has been good to me so far!